# How to get access to this property inside subscribe()?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have property inside component:

```
public _flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService;
```

And the following code:

```
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl.base_path + 'credentials')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        credentials => {
          console.log(this._flashMessagesService);
          this._flashMessagesService.show('We are in about component!', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 1000 });
          this.saveToken(credentials);
        },
        err => {
          this._flashMessagesService.show('We are in about component!' + err, { cssClass: 'alert-error', timeout: 1000 });
          }
      );
```

I can not get access to `this._flashMessagesService.show`?

Comment: There is nothing to do. You just access it. If it doesn't have yet a value, this might fail, but from the information you provided it's not possible to say.

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: If it doesn't have a value, this is not a surprise. Where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: I tried to use this library: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-flash-messages` And call this in success http

Comment: first of all, why underscore for a public property? Usually, private properties are prefixed with _, not public ones. Also, can you please show us the constructor of your component? It seems like you expect a value in this property but you don't have one, since your Type ends with Service, I guess you're using DI, that's why your component constructor could be useful.

Comment: Usually not even private fields are prefixed with `_`, except perhaps for disambiguation between backing field and getter/setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution found out, during discussion with author:

1. _flashMessageService was not working in service (we did not find out why).
2. It was working correctly inside component.

What we have done is move login with _flashService to the component:

Service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private http: Http){}
    public login(user, pass): Observable<Response> {
        return this.http.get("someUrl");
    }
}
```

Component.ts:

```
@Component({
     //some component setup
})
export class MyComponent{
    constructor(private _flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService, private service: SomeService)

    public method():void {
        this.service.login("aaa","bbb").map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe( credentials => {
            this._flashMessagesService.show('We are in about component!', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 1000 });
            this.saveToken(credentials);
        }, err => {
            this._flashMessagesService.show('We are in about component!' + err, { cssClass: 'alert-error', timeout: 1000 });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am sure, also I added this is app.module

Comment: You need it in the component constructor.

Comment: Yes, I dud it before

Comment: But I use this not in component, in service class

Comment: Yes: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined` in line: `this._flashMessagesService.show('dd', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 1000 });`#

Comment: And what is happening when you are trying to use `.sho()` outside of observable? It runs correctly?

Comment: Do you mean outside service? in component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149734/discussion-between-maciej-treder-and-oleg-p).